# Workaround Reserved Words

Tags: sql, ado, ms-access-2013, delphi-xe8

I have a table called `Candidates` with fields `C_ID`, `C_Surname`, `C_Names` and `C_Gender`. The word `NAMES` is reserved in Microsoft Jet 4.0 and therefore the SQL statement `SELECT C_Names AS Names` does not work. Is there any workaround to use the word Names as an identifier?

**NOTE: My method of connection is ADO.**

### Update

Seeing as none of the provided answers have worked, here’s my full SQL statement:

```
SELECT
  C.C_ID AS ID,
  StrConv(C.C_Surname, 3) AS Surname,
  StrConv(C.C_Names, 3) AS Name,
  Sum(V.V_ClassA * M.M_Multiplier) AS ClassA,
  Sum(V.V_ClassB * M.M_Multiplier) AS ClassB,
  Sum(V.V_ClassC * M.M_Multiplier) AS ClassC
FROM
  ((Candidates AS C
    INNER JOIN Votes AS V ON C.C_ID = V.C_ID)
    INNER JOIN Parties AS P ON V.P_ID = P.P_ID)
    INNER JOIN Multiplier AS M ON P.P_Type = M.P_Type
GROUP BY
  C.C_ID,
  C.C_Surname,
  C.C_Names
ORDER BY
  Sum(V.V_ClassA * M.M_Multiplier) DESC,
  Sum(V.V_ClassB * M.M_Multiplier) DESC,
  Sum(V.V_ClassC * M.M_Multiplier) DESC;
```

### Implementation Code

```
begin
  with dmBKElections.qryTallyVotes, SQL do
    begin
      Clear;
      Add('SELECT');
      Add('  C.C_ID AS ID,');
      Add('  StrConv(C.C_Surname, 3) AS Surname,');
      Add('  StrConv(C.C_Names, 3) AS Name,');
      Add('  Sum(V.V_ClassA * M.M_Multiplier) AS ClassA,');
      Add('  Sum(V.V_ClassB * M.M_Multiplier) AS ClassB,');
      Add('  Sum(V.V_ClassC * M.M_Multiplier) AS ClassC');
      Add('FROM');
      Add('  ((Candidates AS C');
      Add('    INNER JOIN Votes AS V ON C.C_ID = V.C_ID)');
      Add('    INNER JOIN Parties AS P ON V.P_ID = P.P_ID)');
      Add('    INNER JOIN Multiplier AS M ON P.P_Type = M.P_Type');
      Add('GROUP BY');
      Add('  C.C_ID,');
      Add('  StrConv(C.C_Surname, 3),');
      Add('  StrConv(C.C_Names, 3)');
      Add('ORDER BY');
      Add('  Sum(V.V_ClassA * M.M_Multiplier) DESC,');
      Add('  Sum(V.V_ClassB * M.M_Multiplier) DESC,');
      Add('  Sum(V.V_ClassC * M.M_Multiplier) DESC;');
      Open;
    end;
end;
```

When I change

```
Add('  StrConv(C.C_Names, 3) AS Name,');
```

to

```
Add('  StrConv(C.C_Names, 3) AS [Names],');
```

I get the error:

**Project BKElections_P.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0062ee2a: read of address 0x000000e2'.**

Comment: surround the reserved words with square brackets, like `as [names]`?  Syntax depends on back-end.

Comment: No luck @Beth. I unfortunately get an access violation.

Comment: confirm by changing 'name/names' to a non-reserved word (name1) and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: The statement works perfectly when setting the identifier to `Name`. The access violation is solely caused by changing it to `Names` encased by quotation marks, apostrophe or grave accent.

Comment: Post the code where you are actually executing this query. Your information makes no sense; changing the alias of a column cannot cause an AV.

Comment: Step 1 when troubleshooting: Get rid of the `with`, so there's no confusion regarding which `Add` might be in scope. Step 2 (if step 1 doesn't solve the problem): Use the debugger to figure out which object hasn't been created before you're attempting to use it. Step 3: Run your SQL statement in Access itself with proper values and see if the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your have two choise if you are using SQL Server or MySQL on all other there must be one:

```
SELECT Fieldname as "Name" ...
```

This ist ANSI

OR

```
SELECT Fieldname as [Name]
```

This ist SQL Server and MS Access

On MySQL you can use:

```
SELECT Fieldname as ´Name´
```

But is it possible that you get the error in .NET and not in SQL?
Normaly you don't get this error if you rename a column to "name", only if you want to access a column with a reserved name in some cases.

So in ADO.NET you can try:

```
rst![Name]
rst.Fields("Name")
```

Or the best think: Give us a sample of your code.
And please try the SQL in SSMS.

Comment: I provided my full SQL statement in my question and I am using TADOQuery to implement it. I checked and can confirm that the word “Names” (not Name) is not a reserved word in Delphi, seeing as I can create a string variable identified as Names without any problem. Access also accepts Names in a query, so the problem lies somewhere with ADO.NET

Comment: I just did some research and updated my question. Check first paragraph second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap any reserved words in square brackets as follows:

[Name] instead of Name

Comment: Looking at your error message, I think that the query is not the problem. I think that putting square brackets in the string is the problem. I am not familiar with the language you have used, but I would try and remove the part of the code where it actually executes against the database and see if you still have the problem. I think the string has a problem with square brackets. Perhaps square brackets have a specific meaning in that language which means you cannot add them. You may need to escape them somehow.